# Why is Coldfusion DateTime returning strange values?

Tags: datetime, coldfusion

I'm trying to use the Coldfusion DateFormat Function. Can someone tell me, why doing this:

```
 #DateFormat( now(), "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS")#
```

returns this:

```
 2012-07-17 16:07:666
```

Why the 666 milliseconds? something devilish???

Comment: As Sean said you need to use both date/timeFormat. The reason it outputs 666 is that "SS" means milliseconds in the context of `DateFormat`. The result is the same as using `l` with the `TimeFormat` function.

Comment: ok. I was reading more into it.... ;-)

Comment: The 'MM' in your time part of the mask is misinterpreted by dateFormat() to mean Months not Minutes. Use timeFormat() for the time part.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

DateFormat does not format time.  Use TimeFormat for time.

**Edit**:

Use this code for date-time output.

```
#dateFormat(now(),'YYYY-MM-DD')# #timeFormat(now(), 'HH:MM:SS')#
```

Comment: TimeFormat gives me 2012-07-17 17:07:438

Comment: What does? TimeFormat(now(),'HH:MM:SS')?

Comment: hm. #TimeFormat( now(), "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS")#

Comment: You should do #dateFormat(now(),'YYYY-MM-DD')# #timeFormat(now(), 'HH:MM:SS')# that will output the date/time as you expect.

Comment: TimeFormat formats a time.  DateFormat formats a date.  You cannot use one to do the other.  You must use both.  Unless, you are using ColdFusion 10 which introduced DateTimeFormat() http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/CFMLRef/WSd8001ae4abdbd9112ab20a5d1350d854529-8000.html

Comment: OK, then the two separate calls or a UDF are the way to go.

Comment: THANKS! That worked. Can I enter this into a MySQL datetime field?

Comment: I typically use createODBCDateTime() for inserting into a database, but if MySQL will recognize it as a date then it should work.

Comment: yeah, createODBCDateTime(now()) http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/functions_c-d_20.html

Comment: One shouldn't need any of these date/time formatting functions - `dateFormat()` / `timeFormat()` / `dateTimeFormat()` / `createOdbcDateTime()` (CF hasn't even *used* ODBC since CF5!) etc -  to put dates into a MySQL DB.  You should simply be able to insert a date object directly.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use the Java SimpleDateFormat where the date mask is case sensitive.

```
<cfscript>
createObject('java','java.text.SimpleDateFormat').init('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS').format(now());
</cfscript>
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

eg. `2010-07-19 11:46:12.029`